# Looking for the most efficient/cost effective way to query my DynamoDB table

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

On my website I have a form with the fields: full name, email, phone #, and message (image below).

[image]

After someone fills out the form, I want to query my table to see if there are any items with the same email address, or phone # that the user gave to the form. If there IS an item with the same email/phone # then I want to retrieve that item’s "sharedID", then create a new item in the table with the submitted form information as well as the retrieved id.

[image]

Currently, I’m performing a dynamoDB query to achieve this (code below). However, I believe that I need to include the primary key (id) in the query. However, this is a problem because there’s no way of knowing an item’s id when querying (being that the id’s are randomly generated).

```
const checkForSameEmailOrPhone = () => {

const params = {
 TableName: "customers",
 ProjectionExpression: "sharedID",
 FilterExpression: "email_address = :givenEmail or phone_number = :givenNumber",
 ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":givenEmail": "xample@example.com",
     ":givenNumber": '7777777'
 }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data){
   if (err) {
     console.error('Error in GetItem', err);
   } else {
     console.log('data', data);
     function createItem() {
       const uniqueId = nanoid();
         let params = {
             TableName :"customers",
             ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(z)",
             Item:{
               "id": uniqueId,
               "email_address": "address@email.com",
               "full_name": "a name",
               "phone_number": "822222222",
               "message": "different",
               "sharedId": data?.Items[0]?.id || uniqueId
             }
         };
         docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
             if (err) {
               console.error('sdk ERROR', err);
             } else {
               console.log('success');
             }
         });
     };
     createItem();
   }
});
};
```

That being said, I was wondering if anyone could help me find a cost effective/efficient solution to retrieve the id of an item which contains the same email and phone # the user gave on the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create Global Secondary Indexes and use the fields that you want to query by as partition keys. You can have multiple GSI for a table and the best practice is to add only the necessary fields to the index (so you use less read capacity units when querying the data).
You can read more about the indexes in the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)

Comment: I believe you're correct. I was trying to query the specific phone no./email address in 1 query, however I believe I'll need to do 2 separate queries. 

That being said, I believe I need 2 GSI's. One with the email_address and sharedID, and the other with the phone_number and sharedID. Let me know if that makes sense?

Comment: let me know if that ^ makes sense, @Caldazar

Comment: @ChrisRose yeah, if you need sharedID in both, then you definitely need to make to separate indexes to do queries. What you can do is query by using one of these (for example phone number with sharedID) and then filter results by using email.